# iOS Reminders change state programmatically

Tags: ios, uiswitch, eventkit, reminders

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFvLr.png]

Is it possible to change this switch programmatically?

I have a switch in my App to enable/disable all notifications and if I could toggle this switch I wouldn't have to remove or re-add all reminders everytime the user changes this setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the documentation you are looking for :
[Calendar and Reminder programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)
Especially [Reading and Writing Reminders](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/ReadingAndWritingReminders/ReadingAndWritingReminders.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009765-CH5-SW1)

There is no way to get reminder information/modification except through this API

Comment: After reading the Calendar programming guide I decided to go with that and solved my problem.

I add a calendar event and set an alarm for that event and when the user turns the notifications off I only remove the alarms.